# django syncing id's from a same table

Tags: python, json, django

How to sync data within the same table in the database and show results for both. For example, this what I want to post:

```
[
  {
  "code": "q1",
  "id": "1"
  },

  {
  "code": "q1",
  "id": "2"
  }
]
```

From above, only ID is different. Therefore I want to sync both of them so that I can get a response as shown below:

```
[
  {
  "code": "q1",
  "id": "1"
  "status": "CN",
  "date":"2015-10-20",
  },
  {
  "code": "q1",
  "id": "2"
  "status": "UR",
  "date":"2016-01-01",
  }
]
```

I can did manage to get display one of them when I use below code:

```
{
  "code": "q1",
  "id": "1"
}
json_value = request.POST.keys()[0]
ins = json.loads(json_value)
id_ = ins['id']
code_ = ins['code']
test = Acc.objects.get(id=id_)
if test.is_cn == True:
    data['code'] = code_
    data['id'] = id_
    data['status'] = test.status
    data['date'] = test.date
return json(data)
```

So how can I sync two ID's from a same table and get results for both of them in json format?
Need help please.

Comment: "How to sync data within the same table in the database and show results for both" what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making it a loop, and filling a list (`data`) with all the results you find.

```
json_values = request.POST.keys()
ins = json.loads(json_values)
data = []

for item in ins:
    id_ = item['id']
    code_ = item['code']
    test = Acc.objects.get(id=id_)

    if test.is_cn == True:
        data.append({
            'code': code_
            'id': id_
            'status': test.status
            'date': test.date
        })

return json(data)
```